# UMVUE for $\Phi(x-\theta)$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

A problem asks that based on sample of size n from a Normal($\theta$,$1$) distribution, we find the Uniformly Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator (UMVUE) for:
 $$p=\Phi(x-\theta)$$

Where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the normal distribution.

My problem is understanding how can I find an estimator for something that is not a parameter of the distribution?

I have tried guessing an estimator and improving it, but again, get stuck with estmating a function instead of a parameter.

Comment: Any function of $\theta$ is also a parameter. Find an unbiased estimator of $p$ and then apply Rao-Blackwell theorem by conditioning on a complete sufficient statistic.

Comment: Thought of that, but I can´t find an unbiased estimator for $p$

Comment: Say your sample is $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. A simple unbiased estimator of $p$ is the indicator function that equals 1 when $X_1<x$ and equals 0 otherwise.